# Why am I getting NullPointerException after second rest call with basic auth?

Tags: spring-security, basic-authentication

Since I added spring security to my project every first time i do a rest call it works, though the same call if done twice reports a  NullPointerException for some reason. I am using Basic Auth. Might it be that after first call I shouldn't send my user credentials at all or is it something more complex?

My config:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/product")
                    .authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

    }
```

User Details service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findByUserName(s);

        optionalUser.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found"));

        return optionalUser.map(UserDetailsModel::new).get();
    }
}
```

User Details Model:

```
public class UserDetailsModel extends User implements UserDetails {


    public UserDetailsModel(User user) {
        super(user);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

        List<UserRole> enumRoles = getRoles()
                .stream()
                .map(role -> Enum.valueOf(UserRole.class, role.getRole()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        enumRoles.forEach(userRole -> grantedAuthorities.addAll(userRole.getGrantedAuthority()));

        return grantedAuthorities;

    }

    ...other must-override methods
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('see:stock')")
    @GetMapping("/getAll")
    public List<ProductVO> getProducts(){
        return productService.getProducts();
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('add:stock')")
    @PostMapping("/update")
    void ProductUpdate(@RequestBody UpdateProductVO updateProductVO){
        productService.update(updateProductVO);
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('see:changes')")
    @GetMapping("/getUpdateHistory")
    List<UpdateProductVO> updatedProducts(){
        return productService.getUpdatedProducts();
    }
}
```

This is my error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.authenticationIsRequired(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:167) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

So basically just an NullPointerException.

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    private String password;

    //proveriti fetch i orphan
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "product")
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "userO")
    private List<Orders> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(User user){
        this.firstName = user.getFirstName();
        this.lastName = user.getLastName();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.roles = user.getRoles();
        this.id = user.getId();
    }
```

Comment: Without more information is quite complex to know the cause of your `NullPointerException` (do the logs provide a clue about the cause?). Regarding to if you have to send your credentials in every request (using Basic Auth), taking into account your current configuration, the answer is `yes`.

Comment: I added the error I am getting, it doesn't give an clue. Only thing i found semi helpful is that Servlet.service() is throwing the exception. If anything else is needed to solve this I will add if needed, I am just not sure myself what more should I write in.

Comment: It looks like your `User` class doesn't return the username. Post your `User` class to see what `super(user)` does.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't, though could you please explain how did you know? Also why does it want to do the first REST call without a problem and the second one fails?

Comment: You can debug the internal Spring class `BasicAuthenticationFilter` in your project to know the root cause. Taking into account the version included in your logs, that is the suitable one: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.2.x/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.java  As @dur mentioned it seems there is a problem with the `username` property, confirmed watching your implementation of `public User(User user)`

Comment: Not sure how should i debug anything when the code used to work on the first rest call, so the server would stop working after I make it. Anyway I am still not sure I understand how @dur found the reason of crashing, I thought this line  "optionalUser.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found")); " would show me "Username not found" in the error log if the username weren't found.

Comment: @aratata Your user is found and saved in HTTP session on first request. Second request tries to load your user from cache. But your user has no username.

Comment: @dur Okay, that makes a lot more sense, thanks for all the help :)

Comment: @dur Could you please check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906358/why-am-i-getting-a-null-pointer-exception-after-adding-spring-security its basically the same question as this one, with just one mistake less.

Comment: did you found a solution?